# CI Appveyor Android Emulator: Can't find any ABI's

Tags: android, continuous-integration, emulation, android-virtual-device, appveyor

On my local machine I use this command to create an android emulator:

```
android create avd -n {0} -t 2 -c 200M -s 320x480 --abi default/armeabi-v7a -f
```

which works great, like a dream, and it worked on appveyor too! Until recently. Appveyor recently seems to have changed where it installs the android system images and tools and what not. (from the local appdata folder to the ProgramFiles(x86)) so I made it use the new path when using the CI server.

So the command now runs. However!

Now when I try to use the above command it does not create the emulator instead i get the error message(note this only happens in appveyor not my local machine.)

```
error invalid --abi armeabi-7va for the selected target
```

I looked into the Android folder and there is the directory system-images/android-19/armeabi-v7a which then contains the various files needed.

I am creating something for android level 19 so this should be all good!

Any suggestions? Thanks.

EDIT:
if I run the command without the ABI specification then I get this error:

```
This platform has more than one ABI. Please specify one using --abi.
```

HOWEVER above that it says something along the lines of:

```
Valid Abi's: No abi's
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my command had to change to:

```
android create avd -n {0} -t 1 -c 200M -s 320x480 --abi default/armeabi-v7a -f
```

Note its "-t 1" not "-t 2" anymore I dont know why but the index for the targets seems to be differnt on the appveyor server.